# Laravel 5, Ngnix web server www-data permissions issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm running a Laravel 5.7 app in the Ngnix server. All my files and directory permissions are set to `www-data:www-data` user:group. The problem is when I tried to run following PHP artisan command from the code using PHP `exec()` function, it is giving permission denied issue to create file under `storage/log/` folder, which is already 777 and the queue was never executed.

```php
$file_name = "queue-log";
exec('php artisan queue:work --tries=3 --stop-when-empty > storage/logs/'.$file_name.'.log &',$array);
```

When I simply try to do it by CLI, it works normally. My `php.ini` is not in safe mode and `exec()` is not under disabled functions list and `exec("whoami")` returns `www-data` when debugging from the browser.
Any clues what is going on?

The output of `ls -la storage` is

```
drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 13 11:30 .
drwxrwxr-x 14 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  3 10:39 ..
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 22 14:58 app
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 19 07:04 debugbar
drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 12 23:13 framework
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 23 04:40 logs
```

and the output of `ls -la storage/logs`

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 23 04:40 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 13 11:30 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  96950 Jun 13 05:07 laravel-2019-06-13.log
```

Comment: Edit your question and add some details - 1) Show us the exact error msg you get (copy-paste); 2) show us output of `ls -la storage` and `ls -la storage/logs`.

Comment: In Laravel 5.4, option --stop-when-empty is not included. Have you  got test a command directly in command line ?

Comment: Hi @dont-panic

The output of ls -la storage is ==> 

drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 13 11:30 . 
drwxrwxr-x 14 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  3 10:39 .. 
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 22 14:58 app 
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 19 07:04 debugbar 
drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 12 23:13 framework 
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 23 04:40 logs

Comment: and the output of ls -la storage/logs ==>

drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 23 04:40 . 
drwxrwxrwx 6 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 13 11:30 .. 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  96950 Jun 13 05:07 laravel-2019-06-13.log

Comment: Hi @gary-houbre , sorry my laravel app version is 5.7 . The artisan command is working when i run directly in command line.

Comment: @SujanShrestha Please - **edit your question** and add those details.  Also, "1) Show us the exact error msg you get (copy-paste);"